# How to create editable Textarea using ActionScript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, textarea, flash-cs5

I'm developing a course-ware using adobe flash. I've an idea to add a `textarea` with every chapter so that user can write note regarding with that particular chapter [same as MS PowerPoint]. Meanwhile, they can edit the note as well. I've only basic idea about ActionScript so I'm not sure how to implement it. I just wanted to know:

- Does it require to create database to save/edit text? if, then what kind of database i can use?
- Any other way to implement this idea rather than using `textarea`?

any kind of help is appreciated! thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Flash runtime provides a variety of options for persisted storage. Which one you use depends on the design of your application. I highly recommend the ActionScript Developer's Guide ([PDF version](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/as3_devguide.pdf) or [online version](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/index.html)). See in particular:

- Chapter 7: Using native JSON functionality
- Chapter 38: Working with the file system
- Chapter 39: Storing local data

The main modes of local storage are:

- Using the cookie-like [SharedObject](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html) to store small amounts of user data locally
- A local SQL database if you are using AIR (Chapter 40 in the dev guide or online: [Working with local SQL databases in AIR](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118676a5497-7fb4.html))
- Store external files locally (such as XML files or custom file binary formats manipulated with [ByteArray](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html))

In addition, ActionScript can create and use direct socket and HTTP connections. With these a Flash or AIR app can work with remote data the same as any other web application, such as through RESTful services (see the XML and JSON chapters), or web server-mediated database access via PHP or ASP.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer & useful resources. let me review those materials. thanks again.